# Automatic sorting cells by value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I would like to sort a group of cells in a column depending on their value in another column.

```
     K      L        M        N
1 Italy    10000    China    80000
2 Spain    2000     Russia   1000
3 UK       300      India    300
4 France   40       Pakistan 50
```

My idea is to sort only the range of values i.e from `K1` to `K4` depending on `L1` to `L4`  and `M1` to `N4` so that if I now change the value for Spain and/or Russia for instance, I would have

```
     K      L        M        N
1 Spain    40000    Russia   100000
2 Italy    10000    China    80000
3 UK       300      India    300
4 France   40       Pakistan 50
```

Furthermore, the values of the column `L1:L4` and `N1:N4` depend on other cells and formulas. I have tried the following script and it partially works, however when the values of `L` or `N` are modified through other cells, the columns `K` and `M` are not sorted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K1:L4")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Offset(, -1) <> vbNullString Then
            Range("K1:L4").Sort Key1:=Range("L1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
        End If
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M1:N4")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Offset(, -1) <> vbNullString Then
            Range("M1:N4").Sort Key1:=Range("N1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all the data (including column headers)
2. Go to the Data tab > Click Filter
3. Click the drop down arrow in column L select sort Largest to smallest

My suggestion is to simply perform step 3 each time data changes. 
If you need this to sort automatically, you need to look into either using VBA OR creating another table based your table (Hint, you can use the Large function and the vLookup function)

Comment: @_user2633359 Yes, but ideally I would it to be automatic

Answer (score 1):

Assume your countries are in A1:A8, your values are in B1:B8, then in C1:C8 enter either a 1 or a 2 to determine what column that country should appear in.

[image]

Now in column L, get the largest value of the column 1 values.  In L1, array entered:

```
=LARGE(($C$1:$C$8=1)*($B$1:$B$8),ROW())
```

and fill down to L4. Then in K1, retrieve the country associated with that value:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$8,MATCH(L1,$B$1:$B$8,FALSE),1)
```

and fill down to K4. Then do the same thing in N and M except for column 2 values.

If you're worried about duplicates, then add a very tiny amount to all the values. To do this, change the L1 formula (don't forget to array enter)

```
=LARGE(($C$1:$C$8=1)*(($B$1:$B$8)+(ROW($B$1:$B$8)/10000)),ROW())
```

and change the K1 formula to

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$8,MATCH(INT(L1),$B$1:$B$8,FALSE),1)
```